# libGDX, how to get symbol from InputProcessor?

Tags: java, libgdx

In the InputProcessor, the keyboard event, I've been having trouble on the way to receive the correct symbol from the button pressed. I understand that the InputProcessor keyDown (and keyUp) will return an int that can be translated into a string value, but is there a possible way to be able to receive the symbol, such as the COLON, :, into its actual symbol, :?

I also understand that one possibility of this for a solution could be to switch(keycode) and go through and sort out the symbols, but I was wondering if a way to do so without the mentioned technique is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Input.Keys class has a static [toString](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.Keys.html#toString-int-) method to convert the keycode into an human readable string, here is an example of usage :

```
 public boolean keyDown(int keycode){
     String symbol = Input.Keys.toString(keycode)
     Gdx.app.log("Keydown : ", symbol)
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that the toString exists to retrieve the name of the symbol, but is there a way to retrieve the symbol itself, such as ":" instead of "COLON"?

Comment: This is the static method contained in the Input.Keys class, not the toString standard java method. It should returns ":" as needed if you look at it's source code (line 506) : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.java

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. It seems that I was actually looking on how to register key events including the shift key. I don't believe that you can retrieve the colon normally in the keyDown event.